# Как правильно написать слово "край"?

Tags: орфография

"Приняли участие спортсмены из г. Волгограда, Ставропольского и Краснодарского краёв" или
"Приняли участие спортсмены из г. Волгограда, Ставропольского и Краснодарского края"?

Answer (score 1):

*Спортсмены из Волгограда, Ставрополья и Краснодарского края.*

Если необходима аргументация... Она может исходить не только из правил склонения слова и выбора формы мн. числа (*Рыба и зерно прибывали в ответ из Донского и Азовского регионов*. Г. Вернадский), и **они здесь не нарушены**. Если выбор стиля, как говориться, был бы за мной, — а в предложенной цитате он официально-деловой, — я исключил бы повтор *город-град*, который бы в любом случае привёл к замешательству (дилемме *из города Волгоград* / *из города Волгограда*) и обобщающее слово *краёв*, как будто бы и неизбежного, но от которого хотелось отказаться по той причине, что оно обобщало не все перечисленные названия. Убрал бы ещё и предлог.

*Спортсмены Волгограда, Ставрополья и Краснодарского края.*

Comment: А где же требуемая аргументация? Не вам об этом напоминать.

Comment: Тут для полноты картины надо ответить на вопрос - корректно ли написание "Ставропольского и Краснодарского краёв"? Очевидно, да. Просто не принято так говорить в протокольном языке. То есть тут уже какие-то другие правила вступают в действия, не русского языка, а протокольного.